# Authorization header not solved from preflight header in cross domain ajax request

Tags: jquery, http, header, basic-authentication, preflight

I want to access a cross domain from https://A/ to https://B/ with `jquery` ajax.

My request header looks like:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: https://A
Referer: https://A/test/index.html
```

Actually on server side all necessary headers are set:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,C$
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,NOTIMPLEMENTED,OPTIONS,UNLOCK,MKCOL,COPY,LOCK,MOVE,HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://A
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```

But my Google Chrome does still only send the obove preflight headers, not the real headers, so I keep getting a 401 error. Did I miss anything?

Update:
Chrome gives the following error message:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got a workaround. I added the following PHP-Code in my requested document.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS'){
    http_response_code(200);
    exit;
}
```

But I am still open for any better solutions.